# if string, save to variable; else, ignore the rest & nextLine

Tags: java, int, java.util.scanner

Here is my code

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    readingInput = input.nextLine();
    readLine = new Scanner(readingInput);

    readLine.useDelimiter(", ");
    lastName = readLine.next();
    firstName = readLine.next();
    stdtID = readLine.next();

    readLine.useDelimiter(", ");
    if (!readLine.hasNextInt()) {
        middleName = readLine.next();
    }

    System.out.printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n", lastName, firstName, stdtID, middleName);
}
```

and here is my output:

```
1.)   Cowden, Amy, 1030440277,  17 15 27 7 19 4 29 101 22 29 14 6 14 89 22 47 28 
      Smithson, Ian John, 1000349923, Randall
      O'Smith, John, 1000453232, Maynard
4.)   Weidmann, Nathan, 1000004345, 7 34 24 108 1 23 2 13 12 67 29 48 14 62 9 46 6 
      Albert, James, 1002334576, Elliot
      Herand, Ameera, 1000399752, Aisha Su

      BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

My problem being that its supposed to check if there is a middle name after the student ID (1000XXXXXX), and if there is a middle name, then its supposed to store it in the middlename variable. If there isn't a middle name, then it's supposed to ignore the rest of the integers, and go to the next line, but instead, it's storing the integers into the middleName variable as seen on #1 and #4 (I labeled them to make it easier to notice)...how do I make it skip over and NOT store the integers, then continue to the next line?? I tried "if int, nextline", but its not working??

**UPDATE**

here is my input file

```
Cowden, Amy, 1030440277, 17 15 27 7 19 4 29 101 22 29 14 6 14 89 22 47 28 
Smithson, Ian John, 1000349923, Randall, 18 54 22 92 4 98 27 15 5 50 12 89 26 95 2
O'Smith, John, 1000453232, Maynard, 7 77 12 48 17 98 0 88 26 79 9 86 27 87 15 51 
Weidmann, Nathan, 1000004345, 7 34 24 108 1 23 2 13 12 67 29 48 14 62 9 46 6  
Albert, James, 1002334576, Elliot, 20 23 12 99 5 45 6 11 1 49 15 92 5 61 20 9 11 
Herand, Ameera, 1000399752, Aisha Su, 20 60 25 56
```

Comment: why don't you split the sting using `,` and try to `parseInt` the required?

Comment: @Blip I actually have tried that, but oddly enough, it's still storing the integers and printing them out. I'm not sure what the problem is, most would find this easy to solve, but for some reason, I cannot get it to work...

Comment: could you post the code when you split the string using `,` ?

Comment: So if there is a middle name, there will be one additional "column" of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need to use `readLine.useDelimiter(", ");` before each `next()` call time.

Second, I think issue is that there is extra space after student ID. Try to use `readLine.useDelimiter(",\\s+");` as delimiter.

**UPD**

Actually, second issue is that, you don't have "," after student ID, so you can't/shouldn't use scanner already. Just go like that:

```
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String readingInput = input.nextLine();
        Scanner readLine = new Scanner(readingInput);

        readLine.useDelimiter(",\\s+");
        String lastName = readLine.next();
        String firstName = readLine.next();
        String stdtID = readLine.next();

        String endOfString = readLine.next();
        if (!endOfString.trim().matches("\\d+.*")) {
            System.out.printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n", lastName, firstName, stdtID, endOfString);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s, %s, %s\n", lastName, firstName, stdtID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I removed the extra delimiters, and tried your fix, however it didn't work; it removed the extra space, but I'm still receiving the same output as before...

Comment: @TheMarkofDom there is update. If it still doesn't work, please include your input in question, I will try it with it.

Comment: it kinda worked, kinda didn't. It got rid of the integers, but my also assigned a middleName to someone who didn't originally have one. here is the new output `Cowden, Amy, 1030440277, null
Smithson, Ian John, 1000349923, Randall
O'Smith, John, 1000453232, Maynard
Weidmann, Nathan, 1000004345, Maynard
Albert, James, 1002334576, Elliot
Herand, Ameera, 1000399752, Aisha Su
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)`

Comment: this worked. Quite brilliant to have 2 separate print statements in the if/else, thanks! and also thanks for helping me clean up my code by removing the excess useDelimiters.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is

```
public boolean isInt(String input) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(input);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It might look ugly, but I think it will work for testing whether or not a the String you get from reading the file represents an integer.

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do with solution, because integers not separated with ",", so string would be something like "14 23 13 16 23".